# backtracking steps for the ending x/

Tags: regex

I'm reading Jeffrey Friedl's book Mastering Regular Expressions 3rd Ed. On page 274, Jeffrey asked his readers to investigate why the regex **/x([^/]|[^x]/)*x/** matches the string (matched characters marked in bold) "years = days **/x divide x//365; /x assume non-leap year x/**".

I deleted the ending **x/** from the regex. So the output of regex **/x([^/]|[^x]/)*** is **"/x divide x//365; "**. But after I added the **x/** back, the output of regex **/x([^/]|[^x]/)*x/** is **"/x divide x//365; /x assume non-leap year x/"**.

Could anybody tell me Perl's regex engine's backtracking steps for the ending **x/**?

Here is my perl scripts for this question.

```
my $str = "years = days /x divide x//365; /x assume non-leap year x/";
if ($str =~ m{(/x([^/]|[^x]/)*)}) {
    print "\$1: '$1'\n"; # output: $1: '/x divide x//365; '
} else {
    print "not matched.\n";
}


$str = "years = days /x divide x//365; /x assume non-leap year x/";
if ($str =~ m{(/x([^/]|[^x]/)*x/)}) {
    print "\$1: '$1'\n"; # output: $1: '/x divide x//365; /x assume non-leap year x/'
} else {
    print "not matched.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the rundown:

> **/x** - match a / followed by an x
>   **([^/]|[^x]/)*** - match anything that is not a /, or is not an x followed by a slash - as many times as possible
>   **x/** - match an x followed by a /

So basically it says: start with `/x`, then match everything but `x/`, and close out with a `x/`.

Comment: But the matched string contain several slashes(/). Then why?

Comment: When the regex engine encounters a `/`, it'll fall into the next alternative: matching a non-x character followed by a `/` (e.g. "//" or " /"). That'll match everything, until it can't satisfy either one of the alternatives, and will close out on the `x/`.

Comment: I deleted the ending "x/" from the regex. So the output of regex **"/x([^/]|[^x]/)*"** is **"/x divide x//365; "**. But after I added the "x/" back, the output of regex **"/x([^/]|[^x]/)*x/"** is **"/x divide x//365; /x assume non-leap year x/"**. Could you tell me the regex engine's backtracking steps?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Joseph is right. When the matching of the second "/x" got failed, the regex engine backtracks to " /x" to have a try and it's succeed.